# Rewrite to non web-accessible script

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a script that multiple clients (with different domains) are using on the same server. For this reason, I'd like to rewrite any request for that script to the file on the server:

```
RewriteBase    /base/
RewriteRule    ^index\.htm$  /file/location/index.cgi [QSA]
```

However, this doesn't work. I think it might be because Apache requires to you rewrite to a web accessible folder from the current domain. Does anyone know a good way to do what I want? Thanks!

Comment: You can only rewrite to a path inside `DocumentRoot`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use Alias in apache config (not htaccess) http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_alias.html#alias